# Línea de comandos

Tags: visual-c++

En la linea de comandos se da el símbolo de la figura, de la cual es necesario calcular el volumen:

s - esfera (el argumento - radio);

k - cubo (el argumento - lado);

p - una caja (el argumento - lados a, b, y c)

c - un cilindro (argumentos - radio y altura).

Calcular el volumen de la figura correspondiente. La llamada a la función se implementa a través de un puntero.

Esto es lo que tengo, pero al correrlo no devuelve nada.

Podrían ayudarme? Cual es el problema?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
double pi = 3.14;

double sphere(double r)
{
    return (4 * pi * pow(r,3))/3;
}

double cube(double s)
{
    return pow(s,3);
}

double parallelepiped(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return a * b * c;
}

double cylinder(double r, double h)
{
    return pi * pow(r,2) * h;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double (*psphere)(double r) = &sphere;
    double (*pcube)(double s) = &cube;
    double (*pparallelepiped)(double a, double b, double c) = &parallelepiped;
    double (*pcylinder)(double r, double h) = &cylinder;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], "s"))
        {
            if(argc == 3) {
                cout << " Volume of the sphere: " << psphere(atoi(argv[2])) << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "k"))
        {
            if (argc == 3)
            {
                cout << " Volume of the cube: " << pcube(atoi(argv[2])) << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "p"))
        {
            if (argc == 5)
            {
                cout << "Volume of the parallelepiped: " << pparallelepiped(atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3]),atoi(argv[4])) << endl;
            }
        }
        else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "c"))
        {
            if (argc == 4)
            {
                cout << " Volume of the cylinder: " << pcylinder(atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3])) << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: de donde obtuviste este ejemplo? veo que alguien pregunto lo mismo  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520026/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Es la misma pregunta.

Comment: El programa lo escribiste tú o qué? (no se entiende por qué la misma pregunta la hace otro usuario... en ruso!) Entiendes qué hace la linea `if (argc > 1)`?

Comment: si yo, guiandome en en otro ejemplo, pero la pregunta es la misma xq estoy estudiando en ruso.